# polymer , iron media query not working correctly

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want iron media query to call a function when the query matches changes and check if the query matches is true , do something ...

this is my code:

```
<dom-module id="example-example">
  <style>     
  </style>

  <template>

       <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 200px)" query-matches="{{small}}" on-query-matches-changed="detectSmall"></iron-media-query>
       <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 1400px)" query-matches="{{large}}" on-query-matches-changed="detectLarge"></iron-media-query>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'example-example',
        detectLarge: function(){
            console.log(this.large);
        },
        detectSmall: function(){
            console.log(this.small);
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

for the first time I load the page , my device width is 1300px so this.small should be true , but it is undefined .

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is by the time your change event is fired Polymer is still not finished with the element. 
If you want to access that property in your function you can use it like this

```
detectLarge: function(e){
        console.log(e.detail.value);
    },
```

Comment: thank you , it works but do you think is it the correct way to use e.detail.value instead of using the value in query-matches?

Comment: `query-matches` is for when you need to use that result in `HTML`. In case of `javascript` `event` is  a better option as now you don't have to depend on any third party library, `Polymer` here to update the variable.

Comment: that's right thank you. is there anyway to check the both query in  a single function ? I want to check if the min-width is 200px do something or if the min-width is 1400px do something else , and if none of them is not existed do something else . Can I do that in a single function instead of using one function for each iron-media-query ?

Comment: You can try something like `e.target.id` or `e.srcElement.id` and give `ids` to all your iron-media-query elements, but check in all the browsers as each browser has different event object

Comment: should I give the same name for all on-qeury-matches-changes in iron-media-querys? and then check the e.target.id? is this the correct way?